# nuxt build pauses after upgrade to node 15

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, nuxt.js, npm-scripts

After I upgraded my nuxt application to Node 15, the build pauses indefinitely.

[image: Build command image]

The local dev server stays paused with a "Loading..." message.
[image: Webpage Loading forever]

My problem here is

1. *--loglevel verbose* is not giving any more detail
2. *npm run build* is looking like it is OK. (I'm not sure though)
   [image: npm run build successful]
3. I can't actually figure out the error from the build log.

Atleast if I can zero on the error, I can try and fix it. Appreciate any pointers here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if [this post](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/8840) is somehow related but there are some issues with Node 15 as it looks. Especially since you've just upgraded to Nuxt@2.15.0. I'd recommend downgrade to a lower version of nuxt.

Comment: I downgraded to nuxt v2.14.0. The build is resuming now.

Comment: This is still a work around. Really feel this problem needs to be fixed at nuxt level. I may also change the answer to a permanent fix once someone points out.  However, you are a lifesaver! I atleast got past the problem.

Comment: I almost missed upvoting. Lol. The thing to keep in mind though... Upvote you give is more useful than the upvote you get on the platform.

Comment: Yeah, both Node and Nuxt are not the most stable in those versions. It's pretty much on their end but you can help them by rising an issue and giving them your configuration. Since it was released only a few days ago, it can be understandable too.

Answer (score 2):

nodejs 15 has some major compatibility issues try switching back to nodejs version 14.x.x

**Suggestion**

use nvm to manage multiple versions of nodejs instructions for [linux](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-18-04),
[Windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows),  [MacOS](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)

Comment: Thanks for this. I tried with previous node versions. But couldn't get past the issue. Issue seems to be with the nuxt version.